# Using my own Product icon instead of Browser icon while choosing a file from file select dialog box

Tags: html, angular

I want to replace the browser icon(as shown in image1) with my product icon(as shown in image2) in the file select dialog box.I am using angular4 framework.

[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QtUSF.png)

[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kt9gc.png)

Comment: what have you tried so far? can you add any examples you have tried?

Comment: Actually I was searching for this question on internet but I couldn't find any solution/example related to this question.

Comment: @mast3rd3mon Any Solution?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately that is handled by the browser it self not the website.